# MS EXCEL Simple calculation for giveaway

Tags: microsoft-excel

I Have three columns

```
Products |  Qty (cartons) |Free Giveaway
```

Product 1 consists of giving away 1 free item on every 6 pieces (1 carton contains 6 pcs)

Product 2 consists of giving away 3 free items on every 12 pieces (1 carton contains 12 pcs)

simple calculation thou but I'm having problems while qty varies for example 13 cartons should find how much time the 6 comes in and should add 1 on every 6 pieces (carton pieces can also be different.

Comment: If the quanty is 13 for product1, the free give away should be 2 (or is it 3 as you said "should add 1 for every piece of 6"?

Comment: yes you're right, forgot sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this formula:

```
=IF(A10="Prod1",FLOOR(B10/6,1),IF(A10="Prod2",FLOOR(B10/12,1)*3))
```

Depending on the product, the quantity is divided by 6 for product 1 and by 12 for product 2. The result is rounded down to the closest multiple of 1. For product 2, the result is then multiple by 3 to obtain the number of free giveaways.

[image]

Comment: @Illeach if (and only if) the answer is satisfactory, you can mark it as answered.

Comment: it solved my problem and sorry for that, I was just stuck at that moment, good luck dear